# SQL big tables optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm at the moment developping a quite big application that will manipulate a lot of data.
I'm designing the data model and I wonder how to tune this model for big amount of data. (My DBMS is MySQL)

I have a table that will contain objects called "values". There are 6 columns called :

- id
- type_bool
- type_float
- type_date
- type_text
- type_int

Depending of the type of that value (that is written elsewhere), one of these columns has a data, the others are NULL values.

This table is aimmed to contain millions lines (growing very fastly). It's also going to be read a lot of times.

My design is going to make a lot of lines with few data. I wonder if it's better to make 5 different tables, each will contain only one type of data. With that solution there would be much more jointures.

Can you give me a piece of advice ?
Thank you very much !

EDIT : Description of my tables

**TABLE ELEMENT** *In the application there are elements thats contains attributes.*

- There will be a LOT of rows.
- There is a lot of read/write, few update/delete.

**TABLE ATTRIBUTEDEFINITION** *Each attribute is described (design time) in the table attributeDefinition that tells which is the type of the attribute.*

- There will not be a lot of rows
- There is few writes at the begining but a LOT of reads.

**TABLE ATTRIBUTEVALUE** *After that, another table "attributeValue" contains the actual data of each attributeDefinition for each element.*

- There will be a LOT of rows ([nb of Element] x [nb of attribute])
- There is a **LOT of read/write/UPDATE**

**TABLE LISTVALUE** *Some types are complex, like the list_type. The set of values available for this type are in another table called LISTVALUE. The attribute value table then contains an id that is a key of the ListValue Table*

Here are the create statements

```
 CREATE TABLE `element` (
   `id` int(11),
   `group` int(11), ...



 CREATE TABLE `attributeDefinition` (
   `id` int(11) ,
   `name` varchar(100) ,
   `typeChamps` varchar(45) 

 CREATE TABLE `attributeValue` (
   `id` int(11) ,
   `elementId` int(11) , ===> table element
   `attributeDefinitionId` int(11) , ===> table attributeDefinition
   `type_bool` tinyint(1) ,
   `type_float` decimal(9,8) ,
   `type_int` int(11) ,
   `type_text` varchar(1000) ,
   `type_date` date,
   `type_list` int(11) , ===> table listValue



 CREATE TABLE `listValue` (
   `id` int(11) ,
   `name` varchar(100), ...
```

And there is a SELECT example that retrieve all elements of a group that id is 66 :

```
SELECT elementId, 
       attributeValue.id as idAttribute, 
       attributeDefinition.name as attributeName, 
       attributeDefinition.typeChamps as attributeType, 
       listValue.name as valeurDeListe, 
       attributeValue.type_bool,
       attributeValue.type_int,
       DATE_FORMAT(vdc.type_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as type_date,
       attributeValue.type_float,
       attributeValue.type_text
FROM element
JOIN attributeValue ON attributeValue.elementId = element.id
JOIN attributeDefinition ON attributeValue.attributeDefinitionId = attributeDefinition.id
LEFT JOIN listValue ON attributeValue.type_list = listValue.id
WHERE `e`.`group` = '66'
```

**In my application, foreach row, I print the value that corresponds to the type of the attribute.**

Comment: If you want to just write data, then it doesn't matter. What matters is the type and frequency of queries that you will issue.

Comment: I want to write a lot and read a lot. In term of space and performance, does it matter if there are empty cells in the table (NULL values take place ? )

Comment: It seems like you're trying to reinvent [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model), poorly.

Comment: If i understand what you mean, the forst solution is better because there will be less jointure when I will Query the data.

Comment: @TylerEaves I will read your article, this may be VERY interesting, I don't know that at all.

Comment: @NicolasThery: do you consider non-relational databases? They might be a better fit here :-)

Comment: Looks exactly like EAV, but you're trying to use a monolithic data storage solution, built for performance and yet you opt to use foreign keys on top of it. This won't scale at all. No matter how you think you optimized it. Once you exhaust your server's RAM, you'll start hitting the HDD subsystem hard. If you want to build something that scales, think about how you'd partition it or distribute across different physical machines and even MySQL instances.

Comment: @N.B. Interesting, I will have to discuss the technical infrastrucure later. Right now, I dont have the scalable technical environment, I'm designing the model.

Comment: If you are designing the model, then think about InnoDB's advantages such as the way it stores the data on the disk (google about its clustered indexes).

Comment: @N.B. I use InnoDB for development purpose only. My production server use MyISAM and I really think that hardware is managed very well. I updated my question, adding statements, do you think the data model is scalable ? (I'm developping the feature since yesterday and just with test cases, I have 600 rows in the attributeValue table)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I now have a query in my question, would you advise me to change my model ?

Comment: MyISAM for EAV based model isn't the best choice. Once the data grows, reads will be much slower than with InnoDB. It'll scale horribly later on.

Comment: question is it possible to just put the group column on the table 'attributeDefinition' instead of putting it on the 'element' table?

Comment: @colighto Yes it is possible to do that. Definitions are not cross groups

Comment: @NicolasThery Then I guess you could do that as well so that you could minimize joining more tables and you could do a direct grouping instead and you could have an even more simple structure and optimize the performance of your application.

Comment: Hello, I just got a badge for this question so I give you an update ! 
It's now 3 years of production with this EAV model. I'm very VERY happy with it. We have 15K attributes, 4.3 millons values and 130K entities spreaded on 676 different applications (an application is a group of attributes, like a datatable).
The model works good so I recommend it to you all. visit www.damaaas.com to see what we do with it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried to implement both solutions and then I benched them.
For both solution, there were a table element and a table attribute definition as follow :

**[attributeDefinition]**

```
| id | group   | name                        | type       | 
| 12 | 51      | 'The Bool attribute'        | type_bool  | 
| 12 | 51      | 'The Int  attribute'        | type_int   | 
| 12 | 51      | 'The first Float attribute' | type_float | 
| 12 | 51      | 'The second Float attribute'| type_float |
```

**[element]**

```
| id | group   | name                        
| 42 | 51      | 'An element in the group 51'
```

---

### First Solution (Best one)

One big table with one column per type and many empty cells. Each value of each attribute of each element.

**[attributeValue]**

```
| id | element | attributeDefinition | type_int | type_bool | type_float | ...
| 1  | 42      | 12                  | NULL     | TRUE      | NULL       | NULL...
| 2  | 42      | 13                  | 5421     | NULL      | NULL       | NULL...
| 3  | 42      | 14                  | NULL     | NULL      | 23.5       | NULL...
| 4  | 42      | 15                  | NULL     | NULL      | 56.8       | NULL...
```

One table for attributeDefinition that describe each attribute of every element in a group.

---

### Second Solution (Worse one)

8 tables, one for each type :

**[type_float]**

```
| id | group   | element | value |
| 3  | 51      | 42      | 23.5  |
| 4  | 51      | 42      | 56.8  |
```

**[type_bool]**

```
| id | group   | element | value |
| 1  | 51      | 42      | TRUE  |
```

**[type_int]**

```
| id | group   | element | value |
| 2  | 51      | 42      | 5421  |
```

---

### Conclusion

My bench was first looking at the database size. I had 1 500 000 rows in the big table which means approximatly 150 000 rows in each small table if there are 10 datatypes.
Looking in phpMyAdmin, sizes are nearly exactly the same.

1. **First Conclusion : Empty cells doesn't take place.**

After that, my second bench was for performance tests, getting all values of all attributes of all elements in one group. There are 15 groups in the database. Each group has :

- 400 elements
- 30 attributes per element

So that is 12 000 rows in [attributeValue] **or** 1200 rows in each table [type_*].
The First SELECT only does one join between [attributeValue] and [element] to put a WHERE on the group.

The second SELECT uses a UNION with 10 SELECT in each table [type_*].

That second SELECT is 10 times longer !

1. **Second Conclusion : One table is better that many.**

Answer (score 3):

As you are only inserting into a single column each time, create a different table for each data type - if you are inserting large quantities of data you will be wasting a lot of space with this design.

Having fewer rows in each table will increase index lookup speed.

Your column names should describe the data in them, not the column type.

Read up on [Database Normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms).

Comment: are you sure that splitting data into many tables won't decrease performance when reading and updating it ?

Comment: Without seeing your usage patterns I can't say - however you'll have less rows in each table, and that will speed up index lookup. If you add a SELECT example to your question I'll update this answer.

Comment: My Question is updated, do you think my model has to be updated ?

Answer (score 1):

Writing will not be an issue here. Reading will

You have to ask yourself :

- how often are you gonna query this ?
- are old data modified or is it just "append" ?

==> if the answers are frequently / append only, or minor modification of old data, a cache may solve your read issues, as you won't query the base so often.

Comment: I will query this table frequently and data will be updated very often. These data are the heart of the application.

Comment: Nope, not me :) By data change I meant : once row are inserted, will they change ?

Answer (score 0):

There will be a lot of null fields at each row. If the table is not big ok, but as you said there will be millions of rows so you are wasting space and the queries will take longer to execute. Do someting like this:
table1
id | type

table2 
type | other fields

Comment: +1 I agree with you. And then `optimize` it with the needed `indexes`.

Comment: I don't get you... I already have a table that tells me the type. and the big table is your table2. I give you the CREATE statement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Advice I have, although it might not be the kind you want :-)
This looks like an [entity-attribute-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) schema; using this kind of schema leads to all kind of maintenance / performance nightmares:

- complicated queries to get all values for a master record (essentially, you'll have to left join your result table N times with itself to obtain N attributes for a master record)
- no referential integrity (I'm assuming you'll have lookup values with separate master data tables; you cannot use foreign key constraints for this)
- waste of disk space (since your table will be sparsely filled)

For a more complete list of reasons to avoid this kind of schema, I'd recommend getting a copy of [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns)

Comment: I do have foreign keys between the EAV tables but I dont need foreign keys between entities. I updated My Question, what would be a better pattern ?

Comment: As usually, that depends :-) Will your application (as given in your example) always fetch data only for one given group (id = 66 in your example), or will you be fetching the data for all groups fulfilling certain criteria (e.g. attribute = 'status' and value = 'fixed')?